# Selenium: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question about Selenium.

**My idea:**

My idea is to make a Python script that logs in to this website.
Selenium sends the username and password to the HTML input field and submits it.

**Problem:**

My code keeps saying:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I have tried this code with google.com for example and that works.
Why is this not working with this login page?
Can anybody help me please?

My Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


login_URL = ""


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(login_URL)

time.sleep(5)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name('uname')
inputElement.send_keys(username)

time.sleep(20)

driver.close()
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that the page does not have any element with `name="uname"`.

Comment: your input fields are inside a frame. You need to switch to the frame to access the elements.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how it works in pyton, im use js
but try to use xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath('your xpath') [maybe use 1 more click) ('xpath element').click() - element is active.
and after use send keys
******.send_keys('username')

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath('xpath frame'))) - in js

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, the element is in an `iframe`. Need to `switch to frame` to interact with the element.

It would be better apply Explicit waits.

```
# Imports required:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://nl.infothek-sptk.com/isps/infothek/?1043")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"body_frame")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"uname"))).send_keys("username@mail.com")
# Code to enter other fields.

# Switch back to default to interact with elements outside the iframe.
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```